# Why does the list monad work when no function is provided

Tags: list, haskell, monads

I am trying to get my head around the list monad when there is no function specified:

```
func::[(Int,String)]
func =do
    a <- [1,2,3]
    b <- ["a","b"]
    return (a,b)
```

I understood that `(>>=) ml f=concat (map f ml)`.Well in our case what is the value of `f` ?
When i say :
`a<-[1,2,3]` does this get translated to `[1,2,3]>>=(\x->return x)`.

If not why does it not crash since i am not providing any function for the bind operator?

**Later Edit**

Thanks for your responses , and while i understood what happens with multiple `>>=` i am more concerned in this simple scenario:

```
    mym =do
     a<-[1,2,3]
     return a
```

What is the equivalent ?  `[1,2,3] >>= (\x -> return x)`

Comment: Yes, `[1,2,3] >>= (\x -> return x)` is correct in your edit.

Comment: Or simply `[1,2,3] >>= return`.

Comment: Which is simply `[1,2,3]`, by the Monad laws.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *do* provide a function to the bind function. If we [*desugar* the `do` notation [Haskell'10 report]](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14), we get:

```
[1,2,3] >>= (\a -> ["a", "b"] >>= (\b -> return (a, b)))
```

So that means that we here basically get:

```
concatMap (\a -> ["a", "b"] >>= (\b -> return (a, b))) [1,2,3]
```

a
and thus:

```
concatMap (\a -> concatMap (\b -> [(a, b)]) ["a", "b"]) [1,2,3]
```

So we `map` the `[1,2,3]` with the given function, and for each element `a`, we then perform a second `concatMap` with `\b -> [(a, b)]`. A `concatMap` where each element maps to a singleton element, is equivalent to a `map`, so:

```
concatMap (\a -> map (\b -> (a, b)) ["a", "b"]) [1,2,3]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
concatMap (\a -> [(a, "a"), (a, "b")]) [1,2,3]
```

and thus:

```
[(1, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "a"), (3, "b")]
```

So the `do` block behind the curtains results in an expression.

**EDIT**: the equivalent of `[1,2,3] >>= (\x -> return x)` is:

```
concatMap (\x -> [x]) [1,2,3]
```

since `(>>=)` with the list monad is just `flip concatMap`, and `return` is `\x -> [x]`. We here thus wrap an element in a list, and then concatenate these lists. This is thus equivalent to:

```
map id [1,2,3]
```

and thus equivalent to:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
do
a <- [1,2,3]
b <- ["a","b"]
return (a,b)
```

is translated to

```
[1,2,3] >>= (\a -> do
  b <- ["a","b"]
  return (a,b) )
```

which is translated to

```
[1,2,3] >>= (\a ->
  ["a","b"] >>= (\b ->
     return (a,b) ))
```

Essentially the `f` function in `ml >>= f` is "the rest of the `do` block". There is no standalone translation for `a <- [1,2,3]`, only one within its `do` block.

You can try to simplify the expression above until you get

```
[1,2,3] >>= (\a ->
  ["a","b"] >>= (\b ->
     [(a,b)] ))
```

and then

```
[1,2,3] >>= (\a ->
  [(a, "a"), (a, "b")])
```

and then

```
[(1, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "a"), (3, "b")]
```